# How to get parameters for the request for a token in large scale matrix of HERE api?

Tags: here-api

How to get parameters for the request for a token in large scale matrix of HERE api? 
I am using POSTMAN to get token.

Please provide details as I am blocked due to this.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/large-matrix/dev_guide/topics/get-started/request-a-token.html

Comment: Hi, Please check this for your solution which specify how to get the token : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276163/vector-api-401-http-error-code-signature-mismatch-authorization-signature-or

Answer (score 0):

You can check check this post to generate the token-

[vector api, 401 http error code, Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276163/vector-api-401-http-error-code-signature-mismatch-authorization-signature-or)

also there is an example.The request body must contain:

```
grant_type=client_credentials
```

**The value for grant_type must always be client_credentials. Here is an example request:**

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: account.api.here.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="1tqA_sample1fLhs2z6_q1l",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1512072698",oauth_nonce="ZGAaMP",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="Q0sample4lqICrx19%2F4ahaH%2Fi2O0NgqDUQJgti5U3Q%3D"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: Currently this post call is not working with pro plan and showing error as message": "Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format.",

Comment: Check the following –

Did you convert the signing key and base string into bytes before passing it to HMAC-SHA256 hashing algorithm.
Did you convert the output of HMAC-SHA256 hashing algorithm into base64 string.