# Here - LargeScaleMapping with apiKey

Tags: here-api

I am trying to use the POST https://largescalematrix.router.hereapi.com/v1/matrix API.
Could you please tell me how to use it with the apiKey instead of tokens? An example would be great.

Many thanks in advance.

Martin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site expects you to do some work, so please show us what you've started. It's also a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Martin Basila, Hi, For the security reason most of the API uses token instead of apiKey/app_code.Hence kindly follow the documentation https://developer.here.com/documentation/large-matrix/dev_guide/topics/get-started/get-credentials.html to generate the token.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Here API provides token as the security reason instead of apiKey/app_code

```
POST https://largescalematrix.router.hereapi.com/v1/matrix
Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>
Content-Type: application/json
Body:
{
    "origins": [{"lat": 0.0, "lng": 0.0}, {"lat": 0.1, "lng": 0.1}, ...],
    "destinations": [...],  // if omitted same as origins
    "regionDefinition": {
        "type": "circle",
        "center": {"lat": 0.0, "lng": 0.0},
        "radius": 10000
    }
}
```

https://developer.here.com/documentation/large-matrix/dev_guide/topics/get-started/send-request.html

to generate the token kindly send this post request-

https://developer.here.com/documentation/large-matrix/dev_guide/topics/get-started/request-a-token.html

also you can check this post for better understanding of token-[vector api, 401 http error code, Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276163/vector-api-401-http-error-code-signature-mismatch-authorization-signature-or)